# View the 'terminal name' of an installed app?

Tags: command-line

I installed firefox from the store. In the Show Applications menu its called Firefox Web Browser (not just Firefox), and I can launch it from the terminal just writing Firefox.

I also installed Midnight Commander from the store but to launch it I have to type mc (it took me 1 hour to notice this)

Is there any list where i can see the 'terminal name' I have to type in the terminal to launch an app?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at the .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` and elsewhere. In particular, look at their `Exec=` lines which will contain the "terminal name".

Answer (score 0):

Application binaries usually installed into `/bin` or `/usr/bin` folders.
 
You could use `ls /bin` or `ls /usr/bin` to list all binaries to console commands and desktop applications.

Also, if you have your Firefox running, you could use `ps aux | grep firefox` command to see what binary path have been used for application.

For example:

```
$ ps aux | grep chrome
user   11182  0.0  0.6 4568428 54112 ?       SNl  13:48   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --disable-webrtc-apm-in-audio-service --field-trial-handle=7356609730568785120,9558563176934852878,131072 --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=181c2763-8134-47a2-bc44-349a4e81270e, --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --enable-auto-reload --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=16 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
```

It shows that chrome binary is located in `/opt/google/chrome/` folder. So another location you could check is `/opt`: `ls /opt`.

Console commands for applications usually named starting with lower case letters.