# Get the link between menu name and real name of applications

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, nautilus

On my Ubuntu 18.04, in the list of my apps (which I see when I press the Super key), I have "Fichier" ('File'), "Capture d'écran" ('print screen') or 'Logiciels Ubuntu' ('Ubuntu software').

But the real name of these applications are Nautilus, Gnome-screenshot and Gnome-software respectively

The question is : where can I find this link, "Fichier"==Nautilus?

Why would I want to do that? For exemple, I want to remap the printscreen key to open to open the print-screen application, instead of taking a picture. So in the keyboard setup, I created a shortcut with the command `gnome-screenshot -i`, but I had to ask internet what was the name of the screenshot app. Is there a way I could have found it myself?

Comment: Does this help? [How to find the program name of a shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214519/how-to-find-the-program-name-of-a-shortcut)

Comment: It does, yet I am surprise by the complexity of the methods. And don't understand why I could right-click on an app to see what it does